# bean validation- hibernate error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, validation

I am getting following exception when trying to run my command line application:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:43)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
        at org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:39)
        ... 34 more
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: Are we're supposed to diagnose this without seeing any source code?

Comment: I am trying to upsert a item 
managerService.save(item, tokenId);

 getting an exception in business layer 

public Item validateItem(final Item item) {

 try {

 final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().traversableResolver(new CustomTraversableResolver()).buildValidatorFactory(); 

validator = factory.getValidator();

 } catch (final Throwable e) {

 e.printStackTrace();
 System.exit(0); 
}

 I can upsert when I run application on eclipse, issue is when I run as a commandline application through jar

Comment: Looks very interesting, taking in account the cause of exception(http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.com/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.1.0.Beta1/org/hibernate/validator/util/Version.java). Which OS and JRE do you use, where your Hibernate Validator's jar is placed, how do you put it into classpath?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.6, windows OS, I am using one jar to generate jar files
below is the structure
one-jar
  - lib(all validation jars, business.jar)
  -main.jar(where i have this method which has transactional attribute which calls my service layer)

Comment: I guess issue is with below two lines in org.hibernate.validator.util.Version class

String pathToThisClass =
38    clazz.getResource( classFileName ).toString();
39  String pathToManifest = pathToThisClass.substring( 0, pathToThisClass.indexOf( classFilePath ) - 1 )
40    + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";

As I am generating a jar file, clazz.getResource( classFileName ).toString() is returning a null, and hence throwing an exception. Is there any way I can avoid this

Answer (score 1):

This is strange. I pasted the relevant parts of the `static` initialization block of `o.h.v.u.Version` in a class with a `main` and added some poor man's logging traces:

```
public class VersionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class clazz = org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.class;

        String classFileName = clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class";
        System.out.println(String.format("%-16s: %s", "classFileName", classFileName));

        String classFilePath = clazz.getCanonicalName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        System.out.println(String.format("%-16s: %s", "classFilePath", classFilePath));

        String pathToThisClass = clazz.getResource(classFileName).toString();
        System.out.println(String.format("%-16s: %s", "pathToThisClass", pathToThisClass));

        // This is line 39 of `org.hibernate.validator.util.Version`
        String pathToManifest = pathToThisClass.substring(0, pathToThisClass.indexOf(classFilePath) - 1)
            + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
        System.out.println(String.format("%-16s: %s", "pathToManifest", pathToManifest));
    }
}
```

And here the output I get when running it:

```
classFileName   : Version.class
classFilePath   : org/hibernate/validator/util/Version.class
pathToThisClass : jar:file:/home/pascal/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/util/Version.class
pathToManifest  : jar:file:/home/pascal/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

In your case, the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2` suggests that:

```
pathToThisClass.indexOf( classFilePath )
```

is returning `-1`, making the `pathToThisClass.substring(0, -2)` call indeed erroneous.

And this means that `org/hibernate/validator/util/Version.class` is somehow not part of the `pathToThisClass` that you get. I don't have a full explanation but this must be related to the fact that you're using One-Jar.

Could you run the above test class and update your question with the output?

Comment: By using one-jar version 0.96 , I am getting StringOutOfBoundException as pathtothisclassname generate different path but by using latest one jar 0.97 version I can overcome this error but other issue is when I am running latest one jar version I am getting InvalidArgumentException on InvalidXml whereas xml is valid, can I skip this validation on latest one jar version, please advise

Comment: @praveen: The provided "details" are not enough, I can't say anything. Please post traces, step to reproduce, etc. You need to help readers a bit.

Comment: my aplogies, following is the scenario
I am reading spring application context file
final ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
"context.xml");
my context.xml is
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"class="..">
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
</bean>


while reading "jpaVendorAdapter" from above xml, tries to read persistence_1_0.xsd from org/hibernate/ejb/persistence_1_0.xsd' which is throwing saxparserexception, i checked xsd file, its valid xml, am i doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

So, as you use One-JAR, the problem probably is in incompatibility between One-JAR and Hibernate Validator. However, in the latest version of One-JAR (0.97) it works fine, therefore use the latest version.

Comment: getting all sorts of exceptions while using latest one jar version, getting Illegal argument exception on invalid xml though there is valid xml, getting this exception when I am trying to read spring context.xml